# Facebook "like" button, Open Graph meta tags - Application ID or Admin IDs?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins

When adding Open Graph tags to "like" button on each page of awebsite, what are the benefits of connecting the pages to Facebook by Application ID (fb:app_id meta tag) instead of/in addition to fb:admins metatag?

Edit: Is there any difference in Facebook Insights between the two?

Answer (score 0):

the`fb:app_id` tag allows that application to manage the pages (publish posts, delete posts/comments, etc).  The `fb:admins` tag allows the users specified to manage those pages via any page management application they install to their profile.  They would also get access to a Facebook Page on Facebook that only they could access, used to manage the page (publish posts, manage comments, etc) but I'm not sure if that exists any more or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "manage the pages (publish posts, delete posts/comments, etc)."? What posts can I publish if it is a website, not a Facebook Page?

Comment: When you specify `fb:admins` or `fb:app_id` Facebook recognizes the object to be about equivalent of a Facebook page (just without an actual Profile page on Facebook).  So, you can publish Facebook posts into the news feed as this new Graph Object; but when your users click on your Page Name it takes them to your website, not a Profile on Facebook

Comment: What is the benefit of publishing Facebook posts into the news feed? Actually what do you mean "publish FB posts into the news feed as this new Graph Object"? Do you mean the Graph Object is the author of a posts?

Comment: Do you mean the website is the Graph object or the single website page?

Comment: Your website is the graph object. Facebook creates a Facebook entity for your website.  You can now post to the news feed on Facebook for users who have clicked "like" on your like widget for your website (graph object). What is the benefit? Being able to reach your audience on Facebook, and bring them off facebook to engage with your website.